# Android tutorial map_view

Tags: android-core, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am working with the android tutorial map_view.
I have the app running perfectly in my tablet. I have run a map_server node in my terminal after running roscore, of course.
Do I need something more running to see the map in my tablet?.
I can see anything about the map. It shows an orange triangle that should be the robot, but there is nothing in the background as a map should be.

Does anybody have achieved to run the android example correctly?
I would be so grateful if somebody could tell me the steps to obtain it running OK.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44838/android-tutorial-map_view/) by [JMata](https://answers.ros.org/users/2907/jmata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2012-09-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried the apk from Google Play?
If you want to build by yourself, you should clone the source and build it.

Your environment is indigo? If yes, try the bellows.

$ git clone -b indigo https://github.com/rosjava/android_core.git

$ cd android_core

Open Android studio to import the project, and run it. The apk will be installed after you built successfully.

---

Originally posted by [tzutalin](https://answers.ros.org/users/22281/tzutalin/) with karma: 46 on 2015-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0